# How to change the default format of JPA generated column names

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, openjpa

Currently I'm mapping new JPA entities to an old database. The column names in the database have column names separated with underscore like 'my_column_name'.

The problem is that JPA defaults to using with camel case.

```
// Will be 'myColumnName' in queries and generated databases
private String myColumnName;
```

I know it's possible to add @Column(name="..") or @JoinColumn(name="...") on the properties - but that means i have to add it to every single property in all entities.

```
@Column(name = "my_column_name")
private String myColumnName;
```

Is it possible to change the default behavior of JPA to use 'my_column_name' instead of 'myColumnName'?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines to your **application.properties** :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=
   org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=
   org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

According to the following link, I tested and it worked:

[Spring Boot + JPA : Column name annotation ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately JPA doesn't provide any global naming strategy. So you should use @Column annotation on each property. But you can use Hibernate to achive this goal. See [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate [Implementing a NamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-namingstrategy)

Comment: which would only work in Hibernate, and he also tagged it as OpenJPA