# JPA column with incorrect underscore

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I use JPA for database access and annotated every column with the correct name. Now if I execute a query (e.g. `findAll()`) it returns

```
Unknown column 'program0_.program_id' in 'field list'
```

The error message is correct `program_id` is unknown because the real name is `programId`.

**Models: Program**

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "programs")
  @XmlRootElement
  public class Program implements Serializable {
          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
          @Basic(optional = false)
          @Column(name = "programId")
          private Long programId;
          @ManyToMany
          @JoinTable(
                  name = "programlabels",
                  joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "program", referencedColumnName = "programId")},
                  inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "label", referencedColumnName = "labelId")})
          private Collection<Label> labels;
        }
```

**Label**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "labels")
@XmlRootElement
public class Label implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
  @Column(name = "labelId")
  private String labelId;  
}
```

**Query**

```
select program0_.program_id as program_1_5_, ...
```

Is there a reason why JPA changes "programId" to "program_id" or am I missing any configuration?

thanks

Edit: Oh sorry forgot to add query code/information.

I use the Spring Data's `JpaRepository` interface and tried the `findAll()` query.

```
@Repository
public interface ProgramRepository extends JpaRepository<Program, Long> {}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that doesn't help me, because the problem is that JPA uses the wrong column name, regardless of what I see in the console. What I have seen the column names are the same in both outputs.

Comment: Your problem may be related with this one: [spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored)

Comment: Thanks that is the same issue. I added a naming strategy to the configuration and now it works. If you want to add it as answer you get some useless internet points.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As described in [spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored), your column name is being converted to snake case.

Possible solutions:

- Setup a Naming Strategy
- Use lowercase column names in your annotations

Answer (score 57):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy is not a supported property for Spring JPA implementation using Hibernate 5.

Use the below property in `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: For me, my cameCase properties in my entity class were automatically getting generated to snake case columns of defined properties in DB table. I wanted it camelCase mapping in DB column as well. This solution worked for me perfectly without much changes anywhere.

Comment: This solved my problem for spring boot security not loging in. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

### Were able to map

**@Column(name = "PersonFullName")**

**private String PersonFullName;**

---

to the database table column name "***PersonFullName***" without the underscore.

The below worked for me. Add this in the application settings and then use @Column to specify the physical database column name for the model's property.

**@Column(name = "PersonFullName")**

In **Application.properties**

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Answer (score 3):

use below in application.properties

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl