# JPA '.'(dot) in column name

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot app (REST API) that uses JPA Entities with a SQL Server 2012 view. In that view I have a column

```
S.N.
```

When Running the Spring Boot App and accessing the said entity(through API), I get the following error.

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name '`s_n` '.
```

I have tried escaping the annotation with backticks as well as putting column name in quotes

```
@Column(name="[`S.N` ]")
@Column(name="\"S.N.\"")
```

**Do note that changing the column name is not possible at the moment as I have no control over the database.**

Comment: did you try others like "`S.N`" ? :)

Comment: Tried all combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by add the following to `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Referenced from this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48442812/8277643