# application is not using user_id and table also doesnt have user_id in users table, but getting error as The column name user_id is not valid

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

application is not using user_id column and table also doesn't have user_id in users table, but getting error as **o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The column name user_id is not valid.**

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to find column position by name: user_id] with root cause
```

**Dao interface**

```
 @Query(value="Select * from Users u WHERE u.UserName=:username", nativeQuery = true)
User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username) throws SQLException;
```

**Table data**

[image]

**User Model class**

[image]

Please help on this

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored may this be the issue?

Comment: @uylmz i tried same as above post given @Column(name="UserId") and added properties in application.properties file but now getting error as "h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The column name UsreId is not valid."

Comment: @uylmz thanks for providing the link, that post provide partials fix and in the same post there is one more link which is second part of fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple fixes for this

**we have to annotate @column for each column**

and have to use below properties on application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

and also we have to use **mixedcase columne names in hyphens**

```
@Column(name="\"UserId\"")
```

Provide links to posts that helped me [@column and properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored)

[Mixed case cloumn name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697121/jpa-hibernate-camelcase-field/35708531#35708531)