# Why can't JPA findAll get the existing column?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Im using Springboot `version '2.5.1'`, doing some simple application by using Hibernate to query data from local database. While using Hibernate `.findAll()`, I've received a error message of `The column name last_update was not found in this ResultSet.`

I notice the issue with Hibernate for reading my `lastUpdate` column as `last_update`. Despite I have specified the field using `@Column` annotation.

[image]

Can one help to correct my mistake please?

**Database**

[image]

**Entity**

```
package com.user.learning.springboot.springboot.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
    // define fields
    @Id
    @Column (name="email")
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    private Integer age;
    @Column (name="lastUpdate")
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;

    // define constructors
    public Student(){

    }

    public Student(String name, Date dob, Integer age, Timestamp lastUpdate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.age = age;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    // define getters/setters - using auto generate function provided by IDE (just right click, generate)

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Timestamp lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }


    //     define toString() method
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", dob=" + dob +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", lastUpdate=" + lastUpdate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Service Implemenatation**

```
package com.user.learning.springboot.springboot.service;

import com.user.learning.springboot.springboot.entity.Student;
import com.user.learning.springboot.springboot.repository.StudentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService{

    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Student> getAll() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Solution tried:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38875123/4311268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved, with 2 steps.

1. Append the following in your application.properties file ([credit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6264#issuecomment-229893825))

```
### For Hibernate 5.0
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

### How to know your Hibernate version? Simply print this line below
System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString());
```

2. Append `@Column` annotation inside your `@Entity` ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708531/4311268))

```
    @Column(name = "\"ageGroup\"")
    private Integer ageGroup;
    @Column(name = "\"lastUpdate\"")
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree it should respect your override, that really comes down to the [naming strategy](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy) in [use](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/naming.html). You'll want to choose the one that works for your case. And, I'll not lie: I've always been confused by which does what