# Get com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I decided to test the Spring Boot. My project has next dependencies: JPA, MySql, WEB. I created simple MySql database. Here is a table from it:

```
CREATE TABLE `rawtype` (
  `rtId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rtName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rtId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Here is domain for this table:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name="rawtype")
public class Rawtype implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="rtId", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private int rtId;

    @Column(name="rtName", nullable = false)
    private String rtName;

    protected Rawtype() {
    }

    public Rawtype(int rtId, String rtName) {
        this.rtId = rtId;
        this.rtName = rtName;
    }

    public int getRtId() {
        return rtId;
    }

    public void setRtId(int rtId) {
        this.rtId = rtId;
    }

    public String getRtName() {
        return rtName;
    }

    public void setRtName(String rtName) {
        this.rtName = rtName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rawtype{" +
                "rtId=" + rtId +
                ", rtName='" + rtName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Trying to get all rows from this table with a JpaRepository method

```
  List<T> findAll();
```

In the log I see that Hibernate executes this query:

```
select rawtype0_.rt_id as rt_id1_0_, rawtype0_.rt_name as rt_name2_0_ from rawtype rawtype0_
```

And I get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'rawtype0_.rt_id' in 'field list'
```

Could anyone suggest what should I do?
Thanks.

P.S.

RawtypeRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import domain.Rawtype;

public interface RawtypeRepository extends JpaRepository<Rawtype,Integer> {
    }
```

RawtypeServiceImpl.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import domain.Rawtype;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class RawtypeServiceImpl implements RawtypeService{

    @Autowired
    RawtypeRepository rawtypeRepository;

    public List<Rawtype> findAll() {
        return rawtypeRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: so, column "rawtype0_.rt_id" doesnt exist

Comment: Yes, it doesn't exist. I have column rtId, but not rt_id. I don't understand how Hibernate generates this rt_id.

Comment: well, can you post the method where the hibernate query is created?

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr., the OP can't do that. That's the purpose of Hibernate (and all ORMs in fact), to abstract that for us. :)

Comment: @aribeiro true, i thought he maybe was using JPA too.

Comment: I added 2 Java classes in the P.S.. I call findAll() method in the RawtypeServiceImpl.java to get all rows from the database.

Comment: It appears that somehow Hibernate is ignoring your JPA annotations. And I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored) answer solves your problem.

Comment: @aribeiro Thank you that answer helped me.I changed  @Column(name="rtId", nullable = false) to  @Column(name="rtid", nullable = false). No camelCase

Comment: @zigfridus, you're welcome. Can you please post the solution as answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: @aribeiro I only have a possibility to answer on my question. If you will add your useful comment as answer, I will mark it. I think this way increase your reputation.

Comment: @zigfridus, that's what I meant. Answer to your own question yourself and then mark it as accepted. It was you who found the solution, not me. I simply indicated the path to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the @aribeiro who had provided me this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored) I found my mistake.
Name of the column shouldn't be camelCase. Therefore I changed

@Column(name="**rtId**", nullable = false) to

@Column(name="**rtid**", nullable = false)

and now program works fine.