# Wrong column name even if specified

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project using Spring Data JPA + Hibernate for data access, but I'm having a strange problem.

In my Entity class I specified these columns:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Subjects")
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @Column(name="InsertionDate")
    private Date insertDate;

    // get + set...
}
```

When I try to execute `repo.findAll()` I get this exception:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'insertion_date'.`

What's wrong in my configuration? Why is Hibernate searching for `'insertion_date'` instead of `'InsertionDate'`? How can I configure the right column name?

Comment: What will happy, if you change it to  `@Column(name="xxxDate")private Date insertDate;`?

Comment: Try to keep the column name lowercase. Some naming strategies apply some camel case conversion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SpringBoot the `@Column(name="")` annotation is ignored unless you set an application property to use a different naming class.

If you don't have an `application.properties`, make a file by that name in your `src/main/resources` directory. Add the line:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

In it and your naming will work as you want it.

Reference: [Spring Boot + JPA : Column name annotation ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored/26546541#26546541)