# Spring boot with Spring data JPA: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I develop a Spring boot application with spring data JPA
is anyone has a solution for this problem please?:
My bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", catalog = "explorerrh")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private Integer idemployee;
private String employeeName;
private String employeeLastName;
private String employeeCin;
private String employeePhone;
private String employeeAdress;
private String employeePost;
private String employeeCnss;
private String employeeCv;
private String employeePhoto;
private String employeeSalaire;

public Employee() {
}

public Employee(String employeeName, String employeeLastName,
        String employeeCin, String employeePhone, String employeeAdress,
        String employeePost, String employeeCnss, String employeeCv,
        String employeePhoto, String employeeSalaire) {
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
    this.employeeLastName = employeeLastName;
    this.employeeCin = employeeCin;
    this.employeePhone = employeePhone;
    this.employeeAdress = employeeAdress;
    this.employeePost = employeePost;
    this.employeeCnss = employeeCnss;
    this.employeeCv = employeeCv;
    this.employeePhoto = employeePhoto;
    this.employeeSalaire = employeeSalaire;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idemployee", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getIdemployee() {
    return this.idemployee;
}

public void setIdemployee(Integer idemployee) {
    this.idemployee = idemployee;
}

@Column(name = "employeeName", length = 45)
public String getEmployeeName() {
    return this.employeeName;
}

public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
}

@Column(name = "employeeLastName", length = 45)
public String getEmployeeLastName() {
    return this.employeeLastName;
}

public void setEmployeeLastName(String employeeLastName) {
    this.employeeLastName = employeeLastName;
}

@Column(name = "employeeCIN", length = 45)
public String getEmployeeCin() {
    return this.employeeCin;
}

public void setEmployeeCin(String employeeCin) {
    this.employeeCin = employeeCin;
}

@Column(name = "employeePhone", length = 45)
public String getEmployeePhone() {
    return this.employeePhone;
}

public void setEmployeePhone(String employeePhone) {
    this.employeePhone = employeePhone;
}

@Column(name = "employeeAdress", length = 45)
public String getEmployeeAdress() {
    return this.employeeAdress;
}

public void setEmployeeAdress(String employeeAdress) {
    this.employeeAdress = employeeAdress;
}

@Column(name = "employeePost", length = 45)
public String getEmployeePost() {
    return this.employeePost;
}

public void setEmployeePost(String employeePost) {
    this.employeePost = employeePost;
}

@Column(name = "employeeCNSS", length = 45)
public String getEmployeeCnss() {
    return this.employeeCnss;
}

public void setEmployeeCnss(String employeeCnss) {
    this.employeeCnss = employeeCnss;
}

@Column(name = "employeeCV", length = 45)
public String getEmployeeCv() {
    return this.employeeCv;
}

public void setEmployeeCv(String employeeCv) {
    this.employeeCv = employeeCv;
}

@Column(name = "employeePhoto", length = 45)
public String getEmployeePhoto() {
    return this.employeePhoto;
}

public void setEmployeePhoto(String employeePhoto) {
    this.employeePhoto = employeePhoto;
}

@Column(name = "employeeSalaire", length = 45)
public String getEmployeeSalaire() {
    return this.employeeSalaire;
}

public void setEmployeeSalaire(String employeeSalaire) {
    this.employeeSalaire = employeeSalaire;
}
```

}

My service is like that:

```
interface EmployeeRepository extends Repository<Employee, Long> {

Page<Employee> findAll(Pageable pageable);

Employee findByEmployeeNameAndEmployeeCin(String employeeName, String cin);
```

}

then I get this error on `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'employee0_.employee_adress' in 'field list'`

My Database is correctly generated and its is  identic to bean generated!
I didnot understant really what is the problem! so please anyone can help me to resolve This? 
Thank you men, If you need any other informations just ask me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored):

> By default Spring uses
>   `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.SpringNamingStrategy` to generate
>   table names. This is a very thin extension of
>   `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy`. The tableName method in that
>   class is passed a source String value but it is unaware if it comes
>   from a `@Column.name` attribute or if it has been implicitly generated
>   from the field name.
>
> The ImprovedNamingStrategy will convert CamelCase to SNAKE_CASE where
>   as the EJB3NamingStrategy just uses the table name unchanged.
>
> If you don't want to change the naming strategy you could always just
>   specify your column name in lowercase:
>
> `@Column(name="testname")`

Plus, are you sure the column is "employeeadress" and not "employeeaddress"?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the name for `@Column(name="table_name")` are given correctly as per Database column names.