# JPA Query gets transformed

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I have a repository method like

```
@Query("from Application app where app.id.hostId = :hostId")
List<Application> getApplicationsByApplicationId(@Param("hostId") String hostId);
```

And my domain class reads something like

```
public class Application {

    @EmbeddedId
    Composite id;
     ...
     ...

    @Embeddable
    public static class Composite implements java.io.Serializable {
        @Column(name = "id")
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "hostId")
        private String hostId; 
        ....
```

Somewhere down the processing chain, `hostId`string gets transformed to `host_id`, So I get an error like

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'application0_.host_id' in 'field list'.
```

I am trying to migtate an existing hibernate / JPA layer into Spring Boot JPA. 
Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try add `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` annotation for `Composite` class. And make `Composite` class not inner. Also how column `host_id` named in the table?

Comment: Its the same error with the prescribed changes. The column in DB is named as `hostid` in table.

Comment: may be dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the Hibernate naming strategy.
The default strategy transforms camel case in Java to _ in database.

If you don't want this behavior use JPA default. You can set it in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@Column(name = "hostid")
```

notice that all are lowercase.