# Spring boot + MySQL Community Server

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I have been working on an application that uses Spring boot + MySQL Community Server as database.

My issue is if i use compound names like `offeredServices` i get this error on my browser:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Aug 04 21:15:23 EEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO test(name, offeredServices) VALUES
  ('Test 1','Test 1'),
  ('Test 2','Test 2');
```

---

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS v;
CREATE DATABASE v;
USE v;
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  name VARCHAR(40),
  serviceDescription VARCHAR(40)
);
```

But if i use short/simple name like `nnnn` it works

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS v;
CREATE DATABASE v;
USE v;
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  name VARCHAR(40),
  nnnn VARCHAR(40)
);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO test(name, nnnn) VALUES
  ('Test 1','Test 1'),
  ('Test 2','Test 2');
```

---

From my class in java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    private int id;
    private String nnnn;
 public String getNnnn() {
        return nnnn;
    }
    public void setNnnn(String nnnn) {
        this.nnnn = nnnn;}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    private int id;
    private String offeredServices;
 public String getOfferedServices() {
        return offeredServices;
    }
    public void setOfferedServices(String offeredServices) {
        this.offeredServices = offeredServices;}
```

My application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/v?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=junior
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
server.port=8089
```

From my pom:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I am not much with:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Because it ignore my initial values.

Using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` gives the following error.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-05 10:26:32.951 ERROR 6528 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.EmployeeLocatorApplication.main(EmployeeLocatorApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table project (id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), team_id integer not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.createTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'project' already exists
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2497) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1540) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2595) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1468) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 32 common frames omitted

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 9.998s
Finished at: Sat Aug 05 10:26:33 EEST 2017
Final Memory: 10M/155M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project my-project: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Show your pom, show your application.properties, add @Id annotation to the entity - is't obligatory.

Comment: @xenteros  I did :)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I get serviceDescription":null, on my browser

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

`SQLGrammarException` is an exception related to sql syntax errors, but it doesn't give to much information of the root cause.

I was trying to replicate the same error using the same attribute names and table names and I found this:

1. The `Test` table creation script is not related to the `Test` Java entity definition. There is a mismatch because `test` table create has a field called `serviceDescription VARCHAR(40)` but in the `Test` java class there is a totally diferent attribute name called `offeredServices`.
2. The create table script has a field called `name VARCHAR(40)` but in the `Test` Java entity definition there is no `name` attribute.

Now lets assume that we have both components related the Database Table and the Java Entity Class. 
like this

Create Test table

```
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS v;
    CREATE DATABASE v CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
    USE v;
    CREATE TABLE test (
      id INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
      name VARCHAR(40),
      offeredServices VARCHAR(40)
    );
```

Test java class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String offeredServices;

    public String getOfferedServices() {
        return offeredServices;
    }

    public void setOfferedServices(String offeredServices) {
        this.offeredServices = offeredServices;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO test(name, offeredServices) VALUES
  ('Test 1','Test 1'),
  ('Test 2','Test 2');
```

Test repository

```
    public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test,Integer> {}
```

Spring Boot Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MysqlerrordemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MysqlerrordemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner runner( TestRepository testRepository){
        return (args) -> {
            testRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
        };
    }
}
```

When I run the application I have got the following error:

```
 SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'test0_.service_description' in 'field list'
```

This exception means that hibernate is converting the `offeredServices` attribute name (from camelCase) to `offered_services` column name (to SNAKE_CASE) because hibernate is using `SpringNamingStrategy` to generate table and column names.

To solve the problem just add a `@Column(name="offeredservices")` annotation to the `offeredServices` attribute.  The `@Column(name="offeredservices")` annotation tells to hibernate that dont try to convert the camelCase attribute name to SNAKE_CASE, just keep column name in lowercase.

This is the final version of Test java class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name="offeredservices")
    private String offeredServices;

    public String getOfferedServices() {
        return offeredServices;
    }

    public void setOfferedServices(String offeredServices) {
        this.offeredServices = offeredServices;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

To get a very clear answer about this go to the this post [spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored)

Please also keep the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property to create-drop

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```