# Spring Data Jpa adding a prefix to queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities Employee and Project. I am trying to create a Many-To-Many relationship between them and [I succeed doing so using a junction table only with their primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334319/many-to-many-invalid-object-name).

I realized I would like to have other columns in that junction table so I used [this tutorial to do so.](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

But after following the tutorial and trying to fetch all projects assigned to an employee, I am getting the following exception.

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'employee_EMPLOYEE_ID_PK'.**

There is no employee_EMPLOYEE_ID_PK in my code so Spring Data Jpa is concatenating the **employee_** prefix.

How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

use the mapped by attribute and  join columns and inverse joins in your code that will create 3  tables otherwise if you dont do that you are going to get four tables.that is 
table1,table2 ,table1_table2 and table2_table1.it must be showing because of other table in which primary key is project_id.
From the tutorial you have posted it doesnt seem like you have used mapped by join column and inverse joins.
Or better  use this site for learning
javabrains.io/topics/hibernate