# I have an error when accessing a field with JPA. How do I solve this?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

When trying to insert values into my table, i get this error

```
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing 
field [private int com.app.demo.model.Customer.id] by reflection for 
persistent property [com.app.demo.model.Customer#id] : 
com.app.demo.model.Customer@6d1c6e1e
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing 
field [private int com.app.demo.model.Customer.id] by reflection for 
persistent property [com.app.demo.model.Customer#id] : com.app.demo.model.Customer@6d1c6e1e
```

This is my customer table. I am using MySql Workbench, and I am trying to insert my values into here.

[image: Table]

And i am using using this class to insert values into the table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "customer_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;
@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name="street_address")
private String address;
@Column(name="city")
private String city;
@Column(name="state")
private String state;
@Column(name="zip_code")
private String zipcode;
@Column(name="email")
private String email;
@Column(name="paypal_email")
private String paypalEmail;


// getters and setters
```

And this is how I am inserting values into my table

```
// Set customer values
Customer valuedCustomer = new Customer();

valuedCustomer.setFirstName(firstName);
valuedCustomer.setLastName(lastName);
valuedCustomer.setAddress(address);
valuedCustomer.setCity(city);
valuedCustomer.setState(state);
valuedCustomer.setZipcode(zip);
valuedCustomer.setEmail(email);

// insert customer info into the customer table
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(valuedCustomer);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

EDIT:

My customer table

[image: customer table]

My user table (this table i did the unit test on)

[image: user table]

Comment: do you have a getter for `id` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes i do. I was doing some unit testing, and it seems like my column for id in my sql table cant be `customer_id` it has to be `id` in order for it to work.

Comment: Check this out, seems like column name annotations could be being ignored without the right settings : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored

Comment: @racraman this is a weird problem. When I do unit tests, the values get inserted in my table. Since i am doing all of this inserting in a controller, is this the reason for the error?

Comment: @racraman I imported those properties btw with no avail. ):

Comment: Can you do "show columns" for both your actual customer table, and also the other temporary table that works (where you've renamed the column from "customer_id" to "id").   I'm guessing that you've declared the latter "not null" ? :)

Comment: hey @racraman, i added pictures to the post. I am not sure why this isn't working on either one when i use this inside my controller. The unit test works fine. ):

Comment: Thanks @Tony - drats, so it's not "not null".   PropertyAccessException used to be thrown when a nullable column was mapped to a primitive, so thought that might still be the case, and be the case here - but you've got them not null, so should be good.

Answer (score 2):

try using AUTO or IDENTITY policy.
like:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```