# ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [http-nio-8080-exec-3] (logExceptions:131) [] - The column name is not valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

trying to run a native query however I'm getting `The column name sb_modelid is not valid.` when attempting to map the return object to my model object in java? I have verified all the column names are correct.

1) Why is it referring to my column name as `sb_modelid` and not `sbModelID`?

2) Why is not being mapped to my POJO correctly?

Thanks!

Model Object:

```
package com.dish.wfm.linkingTickets.model.repository;
public class Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "sbModelID")
    private Long sbModelId;

    @Column(name = "modelID")
    private String modelID;

    @Column(name = "serialNumber")
    private String serialNumber;

    @Column(name = "serviceContractNumber")
    private String serviceContractNumber;

}
```

Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface SBModelRepo extends JpaRepository<Model, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select m.sbModelID, m.modelID, m.serialNumber, m.serviceContractNumber from sb.Model m where m.modelID = ?1 and m.serialNumber = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Model findTopByModelIDAndSerialNumber(String modelID, String serialNumber);
}
```

Comment: Are you using hibernate as your JPA implementation - if so what version ? This post might be describing the same issue you are facing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored

Comment: Is there an ```@Entity``` annotation in your code?

Comment: And please check it about ```jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto``` on your config file : yml or properties file