# ERROR:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:ERROR: column userinfo0_.dtype does not exist

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I am developing a web application in Spring boot and using PostgreSQL as my Database.

I have four classes. One is parent and the other three are children. It's an hierarchical inheritance. I have the fields which are common for the 3 children classes in parent class,When i implemented it and I got dtype error, i.e it said I don't type dtype column in my parent class, then I added the dtype column which is named as userInfo_type in the db and assigned a value "0" to it manually, and in the entity classes in the parent class I specified this

```java
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="userInfo_type",discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER,columnDefinition = "0")
)
```

and

```java
@DiscriminatorValue("1"),@DiscriminatorValue("2"),@DiscriminatorValue("3")
```

in the three child classes respectively

Note:i didn't add the userInfo_type column as one of the property in any of the four entities and neither on the db script which creates the database tables and columns,I added the column in db explicitly and added the `@DiscriminatorColumn` to the parent and `@DiscriminatoryValue` to the children respectively and after I run that i am getting this error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column userinfo0_.user_info_type does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "userinfo0_.userInfo_type".
  Position: 901
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2510)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2245)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:311)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:109)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 105 more
2020-03-23 13:16:21.572 DEBUG 8796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [
```

Comment: Can you show your tables structure?
I would also be relevant to add all the entities classes declaration (removing all non-relevant fields and methods)

Comment: Spring uses `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy`, naming strategy by default which replaces camelCase with `_`, so your column name is being changed from `userInfo_type` to `user_info_type`. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored for solutions, although realistically, since postgres is case insensitive (unless you quote everything...), then it would be best to update the db to use the standard name strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The created (manually) column has been named: `userInfo_type` while when translating the discriminator field name to a column name, *Hibernate*, uses the *snake case* naming prepending an underscore (`_`) before any uppercase letter.

Simply said: `userInfo_type` is resolved to `USER_INFO_TYPE` and not to `USERINFO_TYPE`.

In case you can act manually on the table, you can rename the created column to `USER_INFO_TYPE`.

Ohterwise, you will have to configure the *Spring* naming strategies [by redefining the corresponding properties within your application configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy).

Comment: That is the issue, but you don't HAVE to rename the column

Comment: Sure, renaming the column, is not the only option.
But switching the naming strategy, will have side effect on all fields.
The answer has been updated to reflect the naming strategy option.